# Get Bound Selected Item from Combobox

Tags: c#, wpf

My combo `cbStudents` is bound to `StudentsList`:

```
    <ComboBox Name="cbStudents"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Students}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedStudent, Mode=TwoWay}"
        DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>


    public class Student
    {
        private string _name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { _name = value; }
        }

        private int _age;
        public int Age
        {
            get { return _age; }
            set { _age= value; }
        }
    }
```

I want to get the `SelectedItem`:

I tried-

```
    private ObservableCollection<Language> _students;

    public ObservableCollection<Language> Students
    {
        get { return _students; }
        set { _students= value; }
    }

    private string _selectedStudent;

    public string SelectedStudent
    {
        get { return _selectedStudent; }
        set { _selectedStudent= value; }
    }

    private void btnGetOutput(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Your selected item is: " + SelectedStudent);
    }
```

**Result:**
I get `Null` output. No error code, nothing. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: This might help [How to: Implement Property Change Notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification)

Comment: Your selectedstudent should be a student rather than a string. And where did language come from? You want selectedstudent.name  in the messagebox. Go through your code and think about what types you chose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to select a student by its name, i.e. a `string`.

Instead of `SelectedItem`, you should then use `SelectedValue` and `SelectValuePath`:

```
<ComboBox
    ItemsSource="{Binding Students}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Name"
    SelectedValuePath="Name"
    SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedStudent}" />
```

The view model would of course have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and should declare the `Students` property as a readonly:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ObservableCollection<Student> Students { get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<Student>();

    private string selectedStudent;

    public string SelectedStudent
    {
        get { return selectedStudent; }
        set
        {
            selectedStudent = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedStudent)));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have defined `ObservableCollection<Language> Students`, I think it should be `ObservableCollection<Student> Students` instead.

Then, you have to bind to that collection, not to `StudentList`, which doesn't exist in your sample (maybe you didn't present full code?).

Then, you have to add items to that list somewhere, `Students.Add(...)`.

Then, if items of your combo box are of type `Student`, then property bound to `SelectedItem` also must have type of `Student`, not `string`.

Last but not least: you have to bind class with all this fieelds defined to your view, so you must write: `view.DataContext = objectWithData;`, where `view` is your view and `objectWithData` is object with those fields defined.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface. As in the example below:

```
public class Data : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // boiler-plate
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected bool SetValue<T>(ref T field, T value, string propertyName)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
    
    private ObservableCollection<Language> _students;

    public ObservableCollection<Language> Students
    {
       get { return _students; }
       set { _students= value; }
    }

    private Language _selectedStudent;

    public Language SelectedStudent
    {
       get { return _selectedStudent; }
       set { SetValue(_selectedStudent, value, "SelectedStudent"); }
    }
}
```