# Dynamically select a Combo box item

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Combo box that is bound to a list `Cities`.

```
    <ComboBox Name="cmbCities"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Name}"
         DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>

    public class Cities
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Pin { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to programmatically select `NewYork` in the combo whenever I click on `btnSelectFavorite`.

I tried-

```
        cmbCities.SelectedItem as Cities= "NewYork";
```

I get an error-

```
The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Cities should be a property, an observablecollection of type city. City being a class. When you cast selecteditem as city then it's going to be a city. Not a string. And itemssource should be bound to cities rather than name. Name should be a property of city.

Comment: What you've tried to do doesn't make a whole lot of sense, I'd read up on types/typecasting and assignment operators. You can probably just set the `SelectedValue` property to "NewYork", I believe the combo is clever enough to find the related item in the list, but you'll also need to bind `SelectedValuePath`. Give that a try.

Comment: Ah yeah and what Andy said, you aren't binding the items source of the combo to the list of cities correctly in the first place.

Comment: How and where do you create your collection of cities that you want to display as items in the combo box?

Comment: From the answer to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62947969/1136211) you do already know how to bind the SelectedItem or SelectedValue of a ComboBox. All you need to do now is to set the appropriate source property in your view model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some code and markup to consider:

```
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Cities}"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCity}"
                  Width="160"
                  />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedCity.Name}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

and

```
    public class MainWindowViewModel : BindableBase
    {
    public ObservableCollection<City> Cities { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<City>(
        new List<City>
            {
                new City{Name="Liverpool", Pin=1},
                new City{Name="Manchester", Pin=2},
                new City{Name="London", Pin=3}
            }
        );
    private City selectedCity;
    public City SelectedCity
    {
        get => selectedCity;
        set { selectedCity = value; RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedCity)); }
    }
    }
public class City : BindableBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Pin { get; set; }
}
```

The window's datacontext is an instance of mainwindowviewmodel.

That presents a collection of city and it has a selectedcity property.

The comnbobox will set that selectedcity when the user selects one.

The city's name can then be used.

I'm binding it to the text of a textblock just to demonstrate it's selecting a city ok and the property is set.

**EDIT:**

Let's change this a bit so we can select a city.

The code I have uses prism so let's add a command - a delegatecommand.

This will get a reference to one of the cities and set selectedcity to that instance.

I'll also show you the Bindablebase  SetProperty. This raises property changed (for the property) as well as setting the backing field.

And of course we need a button to click so we can invoke the command.

```
    Title="MainWindow" >
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Cities}"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCity}"
                  Width="160"
                  />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedCity.Name}"
                   MinWidth="100"/>
    <Button Content="New York Select"
                Command="{Binding SelectNYCommand}"/>
</StackPanel>
</Window>
```

and

```
    public class MainWindowViewModel : BindableBase
    {
    public ObservableCollection<City> Cities { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<City>(
        new List<City>
            {
                new City{Name="Liverpool", Pin=1},
                new City{Name="Manchester", Pin=2},
                new City{Name="London", Pin=3},
                new City{Name="New York", Pin=4}
            }
        );
    private City selectedCity;
    public City SelectedCity
    {
        get => selectedCity;
        set { SetProperty(ref selectedCity, value); }
    }
    public DelegateCommand SelectNYCommand { get; private set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        SelectNYCommand = new DelegateCommand(() =>
        {
            var ny = Cities.Where(x => x.Name == "New York").FirstOrDefault();
            if(ny != null)
            {
                SelectedCity = ny;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I don't want to get selected city's name. I want to programmatically select an item ("NewYork") from the Combo box.